# The ways to find API in open source website

Tags: python, api, selenium

Good afternoon! I
don't know where to look anymore, so I decided to ask.
There is a website "https://my2.soliq.uz/main/info/search".
From there, you need to pull out data about enterprises by their TIN.
The Selenium and Request libraries are ready, but for the Request library, you need to know the API of this site.
Then you can write "requests.get (api).()"

Please teach me how to find the API in such open sites

I tried to track it through dev tools > Network in the browser, but the url comes out there: https://my2.soliq.uz/main/info/search/data, but it is not possible to follow the link

Answer (score 2):

a) open the url on chrome.

b) go to inspect -> Network panel & save the request a HAR file

[image]

c) there are many ways to use .har file e.g. [har to postman collection](https://javieraviles.github.io/Har2Postman/) or [har to python requests](https://pypi.org/project/har2requests/)

[image]

d) From the response, use `json` to extract/filter the TIN

Answer (score 0):

If the site doesn't have any documentation for the API then it can be really tricky.

You are correct though, using the Dev Tools -> Network tab is a good way of seeing what URLs are accessed by the page.

In this case, https://my2.soliq.uz/main/info/search/data is the right URL, but the reason you can't browse to it in a browser is that is doesn't accept "GET" requests (the default for browsing), but like many forms and API endpoints it only accepts POST requests.

You can see in the Network tab that that url is accessed by POST request:
[image: screenshot of network tab showing "Method: POST"]

You can use `requests.post(url, data)` method to get the data from this URL.

See the docs for that method [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post).

Comment: One person did the following (there is no contact with him): He
has it like this in the code:
api = "https://my2.soliq.uz/main/info/personal/data?tin= " + set(tin) # api reference

I need to understand how he found this address in order to find similar addresses from other similar sites.

Do you have any ideas how you can come to this address without knowing it

Comment: By using the Network tab, as you mentioned in your question - your URL is correct.
You need both the Request Url and the Request Method.